# COUNT with JOIN and WHERE clause - very slow query

Tags: mysql, sql

The queries on the website I am working on are pretty slow (there are only about 300k records in the database and some queries take more than 30 seconds), so I wanted to find the problem and decided to do some performance tests with some simple queries, here you will find 3 different scenarios:

```
 SELECT count(*) FROM offer_test
 INNER JOIN searchmod_location_city
    ON (offer_test.city_id = searchmod_location_city.id)

 SELECT count(*) FROM offer_test
 WHERE price > 500000

 SELECT count(*) FROM offer_test
 INNER JOIN searchmod_location_city
    ON (offer_test.city_id = searchmod_location_city.id)
 WHERE price > 500000
```

The first select takes about 0.2s, second one about 0.06s, and the third one which is simply combination of two previous selects takes about 20 seconds, this seems very strange to me, I would expect it to take no longer than sum of first and second query. Of course I don't really need the JOIN to count offers in the last scenario (price column is in offer_test table), but it is just for test purposes and understading this behaviour will help me with optimization of similar queries in the system (more JOINS and more conditions in the WHERE clause).

(There are of course indexes on price column, and on foreign_keys columns).

Can someone explain to me why the last query takes so long and what to do about it?

Below you will find explain for the last query
[image]

Comment: You're missing indexes - I know you wrote "There are of course indexes on price column, and on foreign_keys columns)." but that doesn't mean those indexes are _correct_ for these queries, so we need to see the `EXPLAIN` for all those queries. (Don't forget column-order in indexes matters)

Comment: Exactly what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: MySQL 8.0, I added EXPLAIN statement in the post, it uses range, but it also uses range when I run second query, and price_idx is the index set only for price column so it should work fine

Comment: Please post your exact `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX` definitions and the textual representation of the `EXPLAIN` query, not a screenshot.

Comment: Count are notoriously slow ar all times, there is onl one way you have a table with a rows count column and update it every time

Comment: @nbk Please elaborate. To my knowledge there is nothing about how `COUNT()` works that would make it inherently slow, either in MySQL or any other DBMS I've used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the timings may be seen in the `EXPLAINs` for the other two.

The 3rd query is not really the combination of the other two -- it is also counting how many rows are in both tables based on the city.  What counts did you get for the 3 queries?  Often a JOIN "inflates" a COUNT(*) since the COUNT is done against the JOIN of the two tables.

If you need the count to apply only took one table, the formulation needs to be different.

It would help to have

```
INDEX(price, city_id)
```

This is likely to be *better* than simply `INDEX(price)`.  When you add the 2-column "composite" index, `DROP` the 1-column index.

I assume the other table has `PRIMARY KEY(id)`?

How many rows in each table?

Comment: results of join for second and last query are the same (124k of records), the tables have 340k rows in offers and 44k in location tables, and they do have primary keys, but you are right, after applying one index for those two columns it only took 0.1s, all is clear now, thank you!

Comment: "Often a JOIN "inflates" a COUNT(*) since the COUNT is done against the JOIN of the two tables." - yes, but only for `FULL OUTER JOIN` - for `INNER JOIN` (without any outer derived tables or CTEs) you'll get the rowcount of the query's final results which won't be "inflated" - or are you referring to some MySQL quirk?

Comment: @Dai - Some programmers hope that `COUNT` applies to one table _before_ the `JOIN`.  I'm trying to say that that does not happen.  MySQL ignores the keywords `OUTER`, `INNER`, and `CROSS`; it is up to the `ON` and `WHERE` clauses to determine which type of `JOIN` it is.